# How to create a file with a "#" character in the name in Unix?

Tags: unix, filenames

I've tried many commands already for creating a file and deleting a file with a `#` character, but it does not work.  Can anyone tell me the command to create and then delete a file that begins with `#`?

Comment: Note: You should say "a filename that begins with the symbol #", not a file, otherwise some people (like me) will think you mean the first line of the file should start with a #.

Answer (score 11):

The two canonical ways to create/delete files with "funny characters" are

1. **Quoting**, like alex showed. You may use single or double quotes, depending on your expansion needs. A backslash can be used to escape a single funny charater. This works as long as the file name does not look like an option (starts with a dash).
2. If the file looks like an option, **prepend a path**: `rm ./- "./-rf ."`

Modern versions of Unix utilities often support the **double dash** to indicate the end of options. On such systems, `rm -- -` removes a file named `-`.

Note that you cannot create or remove files with a slash or ASCII NUL in their name. If you have such a file (I've seen them), something in your file system has gone terribly wrong.

In your particular case with the hash `#`, the problem stems from the shell interpreting a word starting with `#` as starting a *shell comment*. A good shell lets you disable this shell feature, called *interactive comments*:

- zsh: `unsetopt interactivecomments`
- bash: `shopt -u interactive_comments`

With these you can simply `touch #; rm #` without hassle.

Answer (score 5):

To make...

```
touch "#file"
```

To delete...

```
rm "#file"
```

Comment: Also `touch \#file` or `rm \#file`

Comment: or `touch '#file'` and `rm '#file'`

Comment: thanks for your helping. but if what to create file and delete file using "-" symbol why cannot already?

Comment: Because `-` introduces options. `rm -` looks to `rm` like you forgot an option and thus complains.