# how to create a file and delete a file using "-" symbol

Tags: linux

How would you create and then delete a file that begins with the symbol "-"? Try it.

I can't write the command for this question and I don't why.

Comment: You should think about your career or education choices. The answer [to your previous question](http://superuser.com/questions/269051/how-to-create-a-file-using-the-symbol-in-linux) is perfectly applicable here. Transfer of learning is an important ability.

Answer (score 10):

```
touch -- <filename>
rm -- <filename>
```

`--` ends the command line switches.

Comment: -f is not really necessary here.

Comment: @Martinho: fair point. Removed it. It's more of a habit, I guess ;)

Answer (score 5):

Or, without using the GNU -- convention, you can use ./:

Thus `touch ./-filename` and `rm ./-filename`

Comment: The advantage is this working on any system, including MacOS X.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--` switch. For example `rm -- -test` will delete `-test` file.
You can also use a path of the file. For example `rm ./-test` will delete `-test` file.

Answer (score 0):

The above are much easier, and you should use the './' trick (it would work on MacOSX or BSD for example), but for completeness:

Use `ls -i` to get the inode number, and then use `find . -inum INODENUMBER -delete -print`